# Batch, add filenames to txt in bash

Tags: bash, text, printf

I have a command for bash

```
find /any/directory/ -type f -printf "%f\n" >> data.txt
```

that a put all filenames, (as example `5r32a.xml` and `5r343.xml`) present in specified directory, to `data.txt`. I want to add filenames (using a command) in order to such code in `.txt`, for example:

```
cat ../raw_orig/5r32a.xml tmp_file ../raw_orgg/bab-aux-cal.xml > ./5r32a.xml
cat ../raw_orig/5r343.xml tmp_file ../raw_orgg/bab-aux-cal.xml > ./5r343.xml
# And etc
```

How can I do this using terminal? How can I specify the row and column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
find /any/directory/ -type f -printf "cat ../raw_orig/%f tmp_file ../raw_orgg/bab-aux-cal.xml > ./%f\n" >> data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
for a in $(cd any/directory; ls *xml)
do 
   echo "cat ../raw_orig/$a tmp_file ../raw_orgg/bab > ./$a" >> data.txt
done
```